# Python f string with folders

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to use regex to find a specific file name in a folder, however it seems like my regex is not working.

Inside my folder the names of the excel files are

```
Payments - 2020-10-24.xlsx
Payments - 2020-10-25.xlsx
Payments - 2020-10-26.xlsx
Payments - 2020-10-27.xlsx
```

```
import re
import datetime

filepath = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Documents\\folder")
date = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

regex = fr'^Payments - {date}.xlsx$'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
 
for i in filepath:
    if pattern.fullmatch == True:
        print(i)
    else:
        print('No')
```

Comment: and what happens when you run your code?

Comment: @RichieV It just prints "No" four times

Comment: The code you've given us is not runnable. Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not testing your regex against *anything*. `pattern.fullmatch` will return a method object. You probably wanted to write

```
if pattern.fullmatch(i):
```

That being said, I don't see a reason to use a regex here. You can simply do

```
if i == f'Payments - {date}.xlsx':
    print(i)
...
```

or even better (without checking all files in the folder):

```
from os import path
if path.exists(f"C:/<your folders>/Payments - {date}.xlsx"):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Answer (score -1):

1. First, you need to remove `== True` because `pattern.fullmatch` returns a method object.
2. Second, you have to pass the string that you need to verify into `pattern.fullmatch`. You use `pattern.fullmatch(i):` instead of `pattern.fullmatch == True:`.
3. In your regex, you have to escape (`\`) character `.` because the character in regex matches any characters. You use `fr'^Payments - {date}\.xlsx$'`.

I edited the code you use as follows:

```
import re
import datetime

filepath = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Documents\\folder")
date = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

regex = fr'^Payments - {date}\.xlsx$'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
 
for i in filepath:
    if pattern.fullmatch(i):
        print(i)
    else:
        print('No')
```